# Can you sue a foreign company in a civil suit even if it doesn't operate within the country in the United States?

Tags: united-states, civil-law

Can you sue a foreign company in a civil suit even if it doesn't operate within the country in the United States? Let's say you decide to sue a company headquartered in another country and that only operates in that country. Can you still sue that company from the United States?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You need a nexus

The company doesn’t operate in the USA. Therefore the damage they caused you can’t have happened in the USA. Therefore, no US court has jurisdiction.

Comment: And even if you could sue them, e.g. if there was some sort of *universal jurisdiction* (like some countries have for particularly heinous crimes) … what would be the point? The court is going to send them a letter saying "you must pay 1000$ damages to Sayaman", and they say "No, we don't." … and then what?

Comment: @JörgWMittag you take the US judgement to a court in a country where they have assets and get a local judgement and take their stuff.